# Is there a way to store my MySQL passwords in Node.JS securely?

Tags: node.js, security

I am using Node.js for a web application. The app talks directly to MySQL and therefore, I need to specify the password to use for the connection however, this requires the password to be visible in plain-text within the source code.

Is there a way to hide/hash the password?

Comment: This is often done outside the code, for example by introducing the password into the running servers via the environment or filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't %100 hide the db password and you don't need to. The configuration file which contains the db password will be on the server and no one can access it without leaking the server.

Comment: This is true however, I am concerned that when I store the source code on my PC or on the network in my organisation, it is available in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://12factor.net for a lot of best practices.

In general, never store secrets in source code. There are a number of options for storing secrets depending on your requirements,but the simplest is to configure them as environment variables for the user running the process (you in development, some service account in production).

While that's not perfect, it is generally secure enough if your servers are otherwise hardened appropriately.